# From Imgur to Mashape - Oauth

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, oauth

I have working Swift code that opens an SFSafariViewController at the following URL:

`https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&response_type=token&state=myState`

to retreive a user token from Imgur. 
With this, the user can upload photos to his personal account.
As this is going to be a commercial App, I registered an App on Mashape and changed my URLs in the code to use that endpoint:
[like written here](https://api.imgur.com/#commercial)
My problem is the authentication. Anonymous uploads work perfectly as I put the `X-Mashape-Key` in the request header correctly.
But the presented Safari window is just initialized with a URL:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://imgur-apiv3.p.mashape.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&response_type=token&state=myState")
svc = SFSafariViewController(url: url as! URL)
svc!.delegate = self
self.present(svc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

so I don't get where to tell it the Mashape key or if it's not required, what is then. 
Do I maybe need to change the CLIENT_ID? Currently it's still the one I had gotten from Imgur and Mashape doesn't seem to have sth like this. There's only the API keys.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
I changed the authentication URL back to the original one from Imgur and using the CLIENT_ID from Imgur.
Now the images are uploaded to the user's account while showing in my Mashape quotas, which indicates everything is as expected.
I'm not sure if this is perfectly correct as the abovementioned Link tells to change the API endpoints in general to the new one.
On the other hand, authorization is not really something using an API endpoint, rather it's a webpage with a callback, so ... Not sure! That's why I ask :)